# Reading an UTF8 file, problems

Tags: c#, file-io, utf-8

I'm reading a text file with UTF-8 encoding. Some lines of file includes accents. Something like this: `EdiçÃo`. But on Console and LINQPad output `Edi��o` instead of.

Here's how to I'm reading the file:

```
File.ReadAllLines("foo.txt", Encoding.UTF8);
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't say what the problem is with LINQPad, but the console is probably set to a different code page and doesn't have those characters in its font. See [Unicode characters in Windows command line - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how)

Comment: This.  It is most likely simply a case of the font you are using not having the characters you wish to display.  To verify, run your application in debug and put a breakpoint after you read the file.  If the byte values are all correct, you're all set.  Just change your output font.